# How to frame request using easy curl API from a http request string?

Tags: httprequest, libcurl

I am trying to frame http request and execute using easy curl interface of libCurl. I have a http request in a c string as below. Is it possible to simply use this string to frame request and execute using lib curl APIs without extracting individual fields from http request string?

```
http_request_string = "GET http://192.168.1.2:8080/coxsl/devices/261099914/recordings\r\nHTTP/1.1 200 200\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 8756\r\n Server: Jetty(6.1.x)"
```

Thanks in Advance,
Srp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. libcurl provides an API where you specify different "options" and it does **not** have any feature where you pass in a fully constructed request in a single buffer like that.

Also, your "request string" above seems to also include a server response which then would make it a broken request anyway...

Comment: Any library which can support this, pass fully constructed HTTP request from a single buffer? Thanks.

Comment: Why send the full request like that? You can make that same request with libcurl, just not sent in as a full buffer.